# SAXException thrown on Jenkins

Tags: java, xml, maven, jenkins, sax

I'm facing a weird issue. I am trying to create an XML schema in order to validate a file. I'm doing the following in my function:

```
 String schemaFilename = ApplicationConfiguration.xsdConfiguration.getTypeMappings().get(fileType);
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File schemaFile = new File(classLoader.getResource(ApplicationConfiguration.xsdConfiguration.getXsdSchemasLocation()+schemaFilename).getFile());

        final SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = null;
        try
        {
            schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
        }
        catch (SAXException e) {
            logger.error("Could not instantiate XSD schema from file: {}", schemaFile.getName());
            e.printStackTrace();
            validXML = false;
        }
```

When I run my tests on Windows either via Intellij or via Maven it all works fine. When I'm trying to build on Jenkins, running on Centos I'm getting SAXExceptions (edited stack-trace)

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/...myfile.xsd; lineNumber: 48; columnNumber: 39; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'AnElement' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
```

Any ideas on what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to copy your xsd content and validate it locally using tool like [this one](http://www.datatoolkits.com/xml/validation.html) and check if there is any invalid content.
If yes, that means the xsd generated in CI has some issue, you need check your code.